# Define outgoing ip address when using ssh

Tags: ssh

I have an ubuntu server machine (12.04) with 4 IP addresses for different websites that require unique ssl certificates.

I sometimes ssh out from this box and the box I am going to I have to tell it what IP address I will be coming from.

How do I specify which of the 4 ip addresses I want to use as my outgoing IP address?

If i do an ifconfig it appears that I am going out as the last ipaddress.

I guess you would want to specify either the address or the interface....

Thanks in advance!

-Mark

Answer (score 11):

From ssh(1)

```
 -b bind_address
         Use bind_address on the local machine as the source address of
         the connection.  Only useful on systems with more than one
         address.
```

If this doesn't do what you want then you will have to configure routing (with `ip route`) in such a way that the preferred interface is used for the connection.

Comment: Any ideas how to use it? `ssh -b192.154.12.1`? When I do this it just displays the usage options

Comment: @JamieHutber - `ssh -b 192.154.12.1 username@destinationhost`